# Email UI customization

Tags: email

I want to customize the Emailing UI as shown in he snapshot below:

[image]

I am trying to add a Print button to the above UI to Print the template. How can i achieve this? Is there any other way to do this?
​Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to this is there is no way to customize this yet .You may want to raise an idea on [ideaxchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) .

Technically you can rebuild the entire functionality and component again if the requirement is mission critical .Please note that do not use CK editor or ui:inputRich as those are no more locker complaint.

You can use http://quilljs.com for building this all from scratch but would strongly recommend not to do unless it is very critical

Comment: Thanks Mohith for the quick response. I will check what other options i have to achieve what i want to.

Comment: However, the other global actions like "Log a Call","New Task","New Event" can be customized to add custom fields or Buttons. So, i was hoping the above customization would also be possible.